# Error in ZipOutputStream + FTPClient

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I've to upload a zip file to ftp server, And here zip file also constructing dynamically.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class CommonsNet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            client.connect("127.0.0.1");
            client.login("phani", "phani");
            String filename = "D://junk.pdf";
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
            byte[] bs = IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);
            fis.close();
            OutputStream outputStream = client.storeFileStream("remote.zip");

            ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);

            zipOutputStream.setLevel(ZipOutputStream.STORED);
            addOneFileToZipArchive(zipOutputStream,
                    "junk.pdf", bs);
            zipOutputStream.close();

            outputStream.close();

            client.logout();
            System.out.println("Transfer done");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                client.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void addOneFileToZipArchive(ZipOutputStream zipStream,
            String fileName, byte[] content) throws Exception {
        ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = new ZipArchiveEntry(fileName);
        zipStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        zipStream.write(content);
        zipStream.flush();
        zipStream.closeEntry();
    }
}
```

After executing this code the file is successfully created but i am unable to open  a file inside archive.
like :

```
!   D:\phani\remote.zip: The archive is corrupt
!   D:\phani\remote.zip: Checksum error in C:\Users\BHAVIR~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\Rar$DIa0.489\MCReport.pdf. The file is corrupt
```

Comment: I tried in one more way first i created a zip filw in local server (working fine) and then i am saving in webserver using below code      fis=new FileInputStream("D://local.zip");
   client.storeFile("dump.zip", fis);    Still i am unable to open a file inside archive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);` just after you have logged in.

I remember that default transfer mode is ASCII, so non-ascii files may result corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, its working, Earlier i used FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE as fileType. why FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE is not working properly.